# On existence of pointers

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, vector

I have a simple question.
If I have a code like this:

```
void Holder::Add()
{
    Dish * obj = new Dish(this->screen_width, this->screen_height);
    this->dish_array.push_back(obj);
}
```

where dish_array is declared like so:

```
vector <Dish*> dish_array;
```

will the object that "* obj" pointer is pointing to "exist" outside of this function?

Comment: Please don't store raw pointers in containers unless you *absolutely* can't avoid it (which is extremely seldom), they are a maintenance nightmare and a big source of bugs/leaks. Prefer containers that store either plain objects (`vector<Dish>`) or at least smart pointers (`vector<unique_ptr<Dish>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<Dish>>`). As an example to what I just said: your two lines of code (`new/push_back`) can leak memory since they are not exception-safe. And this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @JapeCorbel I forgot to say, nice title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it certainly will. However, there are two ways you could define "exist":

1) Can you reference/use it outside of the function? In this case, you can, because your `obj` value was put into the `dish_array` variable, which now stores a reference to the object you created.

2) Is the object still in memory? In this case, again yes. You never free the object. However, if you never had the line `this->dish_array.push_back(obj)`, then the object would still be in memory, but you would not be able to reference it. This would be a *memory leak*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is a side effect of `new` which allocates in the free store, and therefore requires you to apply manual cleanup.

Comment: Not really a side effect. It's the intended behaviour, and that, is in some case, one of the advantage of `new` over stack variables.

Comment: It is certainly the intended behaviour, but still is a side effect as it alters program state. A function which modifies program state is said to have side-effects whereas a pure function (no state involved) does not. That is, repeated invocation of the function will not repeatedly do the same thing, despite seeming appearances to the contrary. In this case repeated invocation of `new` will not result in repeated creation of the *same* object (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are specifically requesting with the `new` keyword that your new instance of `Dish` be kept alive (not garbage) even after `Holder::Add` returns. It will remain on the heap until you free its memory with `delete`. Don't forget to do that at some point, because otherwise you'll have a memory leak!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the call to new returns a pointer to the allocated memory. You are storing a copy of this pointer in your `vector`. The allocated memory will persist until you actively call delete on the pointer. To avoid a memory leak in your code, you will need to iterate over the pointers in your vector and call delete on them before your vector goes out of scope (wherever that may be). Unless of course you are erasing them at some other point and calling delete on them at that point. 
When a vector is destroyed, all items in the vector are also destroyed - in this case you only have pointers, and so even though the pointer is destroyed, the memory that they point to is not freed until you call delete on that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no garbage collection of any sort. Any memory allocated on the heap using `malloc`or `new`will exist until released manually, using `free`or `delete`. So yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The vector in your code sample is entirely irrelevant to your question. All that matters is the `new` keyword. Objects you allocate with `new` remain in memory until 1) you `delete` the pointer or 2) your program ends and the OS reclaims your memory. If your vector goes out of scope and all the pointers disappear, the objects they pointed to STILL exist and are now leaked.

Every `new` should have a corresponding `delete` or you should put the pointer you get into something which takes care of that for you (like a `shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the unnamed object of type `Dish` that you created with `new` will continue to exist outside the function.

However, this has nothing to do with "existence of pointers", which you referred to in the title of your question. The unnamed object has type `Dish`. It is not a pointer. It has no relation to your `obj` pointer whatsoever.

The pointer `obj` will disappear once the function exits, while the unnamed `Dish` object it used to point to will live on. It is your responsibility to make sure that the value of `obj` pointer gets stored somewhere before `obj` disappears. That way you can continue to maintain assess to that unnamed `Dish` object you created with `new`.